# add html game to c# from

Tags: c#

I need some help with a C# problem. I added a HTML game I made in flash to my form, using the WebBrowser control. It works perfectly but I would like to make the url relative to the drive the program is running from. for example I am saving it to a flash drive (E:/) but if i take the flash out and connect it to another computer, the flash will most probably not be associated with the E:/ drive, so that I'll have to edit the url in order to get it working. I desperately need this because this for a major project in school. :D

Answer (score 3):

You should use relative paths like `.\flash\myGame.flv`, where `.` (dot) mean your programm's directory.
You can get more about relative paths [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247%28VS.85%29.aspx#fully_qualified_vs._relative_paths).